# Properly importing from the python package for internal package needs

Tags: python

I am wondering which of these two styles is correct, from the perspective of a library python file that lives within the library itself, not external.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/common.py

```
from pandas._libs import lib, tslibs
from pandas import compat
from pandas.compat import iteritems, PY36, OrderedDict
```

vs

```
from .._libs import lib, tslibs
import ..compat
from ..compat import iteritems, PY36, OrderedDict
```

The latter seems better for local development and testing as every small change doesn't have to be packaged to be tested.

But I've seen that both Django and Pandas use the former method. Why? I see no positive tradeoff and only a negative tradeoff in requiring repackaging for local dev and test workflow.

Comment: It's a preference of readability and traceability: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: Thanks for the link! What about testing though? Say I run core/common.py after I modify it and ../_libs/lib.py. Isn't the import pandas._libs.lib still going to pull from the packaged location, whereas import .._libs.lib is going to pull from the development location. In other words, isn't the package_name.path.to.module going to require a re-packaging every time to test a change?